# Ms. Excel , point cell with value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: table]

[image: Problem]

I have 1 table with 'row a to d' and 'column 1 to 4'
these had a value, example : 
'row a and column 1 had value 1000 (on cell B3)'
, 'row a and column 2 had value 1100 (on cell B4)'
, etc

So my question is, how can I get the value from 'row a and column 1 (cell B3)' if I write code like 'a/1' on cell J3. And if i write 'a/2' on cell J3, i can get value from  'row a and column 2 (cell B4)' (make dynamic)

Comment: Are you getting your rows and columns confused?  The image shows rows 1:4 and columns A:F.  Are these in line with the row and column number/letters that Excel uses?  i.e. is your column A equal to Excels column A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with the text of your question rather than the image:
`=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MID($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)+1,LEN($J$3))+1,4),"1","") & CELL("col",INDIRECT(LEFT($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)-1)&"1"))+2)`

This part of the formula returns the real column letter:
`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MID($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)+1,LEN($J$3))+1,4),"1","")`
e.g. 1 = B, 2 = C, 26 = AA, 1000 = ALM

This part of the formula returns the real row number:
`=CELL("col",INDIRECT(LEFT($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)-1)&"1"))+2`
e.g. A=3, B = 4, AA = 29, ALM = 1003

Stick both formula together to get the cell reference:
`=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MID($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)+1,LEN($J$3))+1,4),"1","") & CELL("col",INDIRECT(LEFT($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)-1)&"1"))+2`

Use `INDIRECT` to turn it into a real cell reference.

I don't think that's what you're after though - but A/1 returns B3, A/2 returns C3 (ok, it falls over there but I figured it out so I'm going to post it!).

Comment: it works but how can i get the value from cells B3 ?

Comment: i want to get the value from cell B3 (1000)

Comment: Just wrap the formula in an `INDIRECT` function:  `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MID($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)+1,LEN($J$3))+1,4),"1","") & CELL("col",INDIRECT(LEFT($J$3,FIND("/",$J$3)-1)&"1"))+2)`.  I'm pretty sure this isn't the formula you're after though as it doesn't work with A/2.

Answer (score 0):

Just write on cell J3 '=cell_to_reference', without quotes obviously.

Comment: i want to make dynamic, so if i change the code to a/2 that will bring value on cell B4

Comment: You should try to explain it better, I'ts unclear. In Excel you can reference any cell from any other cell, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: make dynamic, so if i write 'a/1' on cell J3 i can get result from cell B3, then if i change into 'a/2' on cell J3 i can get result from cell B4

Comment: So basically your 'a' is your Row of the table and '1' is the Coloumn of the table. Now when you write 'a/1' in J3 your are expecting B3 to be out put. My question is where do you want this B3 to be placed. I mean in any other cell?. Will be good if you can put a screen print with sample data and expected output

Comment: This has no sense. I mean if you have an excel 4x4 table, with cells from A1 to D4, if you write on J3 '=A1' you will get the value stored on cell A1 and if you write '=A2' you will get that one. Having said that, the values stored in that 4x4 table don't have to be neccesary numbers, thus, suppose you write in A1 '=B3' and in A2 '=B4'. Then, if you write in J3 '=A1' it will show B3 value, and if you write '=A2' it will show B4 value.